# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild: Child name '/' is not unique

Tags: java, tomcat7

### java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name '/' is not unique

*facing this problem when replacing existing .war files by enable and disable smal single sign on  with in tomcat webapps folder*
**i am using apache-tomcat-7.0.53**

Comment: that means you have multiple request mapping for '/'.

Comment: thanks  Nikson Kanti Paul, but this is not issue in my case.this errors comes when replace existing x.war with new x.war with automatic process.

Comment: please add exception trace,

Comment: SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /common/log/taos-log-a/tomcat/webapps/x.war
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name '/x' is not unique
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the symptoms, I suspect that you have somehow managed to deploy `x.war` twice.

I suspect that either you explicitly did this (i.e. you did deploy / deploy instead of deploy / redeploy) or your "automatic process" did it.

If this is not the problem, you are going to need to provide more detailed information on what you are doing, and how you are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are setting in `apache-tomcat-7.0.70\conf\server.xml`with content

```
<Context docBase="xxx" path="/" />
```

It is duplicate with the other Context

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe set **apache-tomcat-7.0.70\conf\server.xml** with Host

`< HOST name='/' .../>`, and it has other one which is duplicated